# How to seperate the collision detection in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and I'm making a 2d game. Game has an enemy which has a shield with it. The shield( child) has a shield manager script and a collider with it. When it collides with the player it pushed the player back and destroys itself.

And the Enemy(Parent) has an enemy controller script. It has a collider too. And the enemy contoller has an OnCollisionEnter2D function in it for detecting if the player attacks it. But the parents OnColliderEnter2D function being triggered in both of the colliders.

So shield are being destroyed but also the enemy are also too. The parent detects its child's collider.

How can I seperate them?

Is there a way to find which one of this colliders are colliding with the player?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] rather than talk about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can put enemy and shield in different layers. And in layer collision matrix, you can disable collision detection between these two layers.

You can find layer collision matrix in Edit > project settings > physics